# Getting a value from an object php

Tags: php, variables, object, stdclass, var-dump

I used var_dump on an object in my code. `print var_dump( $$user);`

result: `object(stdClass)#35 (1) { ["user1_ready"]=>  string(1) "0" }` How do I get to this value (0 in this case).

I tried print $$user which resulted in `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in`

I need something like `if($$user == 0){echo "error message") else {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the property/method accessor "->". It generally follows:

`$object->method()` or `$object->property`

so yours would be

`$$user->user1_ready`